# How can I simulate implicit parameters in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have found implicit parameters in Scala very useful and I want to have equivalent functionality in Typescript.  Let me give an example:

```
interface Witness<T> {
  describe(t: T): void;
}

class X {
  foo<T>(t: T, witness: Witness<T>) {
    witness.describe(t);
  }
}

const stringWitness: Witness<string> = {
    describe(a: string): void {
      console.log(`The string, in all caps: ${a.toUpperCase()}`);
    }
}

const numberWitness: Witness<number> = {
    describe(b: number): void {
      console.log(`the number, plus one: ${b+1}`);
    }
}

class X {
  foo<T>(t: T, witness: Witness<T>) {
    witness.describe(t);
  }
}

const x = new X();    
x.foo( "Bob", stringWitness);
x.foo(5, numberWitness);
```

This code compiles and does what you would expect.  More important, errors like `x.foo("Bob", numberWitness)` do *not* compile.  This pattern allows me to augment existing types with additional functionality.

What I would like to do, and what Scala implicits allow me to do, is "automate" the selection of the second parameter:

```
class X {  
  foo<number>(t: number, witness = numberWitness);
  foo<string>(t: string, witness = stringWitness);
  foo<T>(t: T, witness: Witness<T>) {
    witness.describe(t);
  }
}

const x = new X();    
x.foo("Bob");
x.foo(5);
```

The only problem with this code is that it doesn't compile in Typescript.

I am looking for a way to designate a default parameter in certain situations, given the type of other parameters.  Any suggestions?

**NB:** I am looking for a way to designate a default parameter.  I am not looking for alternative ways to address the problem in the example, such as run-time detection.  That was just an example.  I have several uses for this that are just too complicated to explain in detail here.

Comment: TypeScript compiles to JavaScript with the static type system [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure). If you want `x.foo()` to exhibit different runtime behavior based on its parameter(s), then you *must* use runtime detection. You can use the type system to denote that `X.foo(t: number | string)` and `X.foo<T>(t: T, witness: Witness<T>)` are both valid call signatures, but you can't make the type system choose `numberWitness` or `stringWitness`. Since you're not interested in alternatives, I guess I can't answer this to your satisfaction.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz — you know, when I posted this, I was thinking of adding "Don't tell me it's impossible because of type-erasure: Scala uses type-erasure and has implicits." Implicits are implemented entirely with compile-time analysis.

Comment: In Java-related languages, type erasure is usually restricted to generic type parameters and the like, and not the full static type system as done in TypeScript. If the Scala compiler emits different bytecode for `x.foo(y)` depending on the type of `y`, then it's not doing type erasure here.  Or, ignoring the problematic phrase "type erasure", it's an explicit [non-goal of TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) (see #5) to emit different runtime code based on results of the type system, so it still is a non-starter as far as I can tell.

Comment: Does [this feature suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16659) cover your use case?  It's marked as out-of-scope for TypeScript due to the general prohibition against type-driven emit. Therefore I'd be very surprised if you'll get an answer you find satisfying.  Despite that, I'm happy to write these musings up as an answer, unless you're still holding out hope for a different response.  Anyway, good luck in your pursuits!

Comment: @jcalz — haha, yes, that feature suggestion is almost word-for-word what I want, but if it's explicits an anti-goal to "emit different code based on the results of the type system", then this is and always will be impossible in Typescript — as will simpler things like function-overloading resolution.  I wonder if that part of the goal is up for reconsideration.  Implicits are super-useful. (If you feel like promoting that comment to an answer, I would accept it.)